# How do I click on the dynamic Twitter follow button with selenium and python?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to click on twitter's follow button, but it is dynamic and has attributes, which I don't find much about on the selenium documentation.This is the html of the button:

[image: Screenshot of code]

This is currently my follow function:

```
    def follow(driver, username):
        driver.get('https://twitter.com/' + username)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        follow = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'follow-button')))
        follow.click()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Also, please post your code, and not a screenshot. Imgur (at the time of writing this comment) is having issues, so I can't see the code.

Answer (score 1):

try this  xpath

```
(//span[text()='Follow']/ancestor::div[@role='button'])[1]
```

Index `[1]` will always pick the first Follow button, in case if there are multiple Follow buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Xpath to click on the `Follow`

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
follow = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Follow"]')))
follow.click()
```

OR

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
follow = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(.,"Follow")]')))
follow.click()
```

---

You are getting `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation` because follow.click() was not inline in your initial code.Try now.

```
def follow(driver, username):
    driver.get('https://twitter.com/' + username)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    follow = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Follow"]')))
    follow.click()
```

Comment: I get the following error:  follow = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Follow"]'))) TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: I have added the function as well just try now.